# Codename One: Starting portrait app in landscape orientation and getDisplayWidth()

Tags: android, width, codenameone, display, landscape-portrait

My app should only run in portrait and not in landscape orientation. For iOS this is a build hint (ios.interface_orientation) which works fine. For Android this has to be set in code using lockOrientation(true), which I put in public void init(Object context). After locking the orientation I call getDisplayWidth() in public void start(). When I start/test the app on an Android device that is in landscape orientation I run into problems. Apparently switching orientation takes time and **sometimes** the returned display width is actually the display height. I tried wrapping the code using getDisplayWidth() in a callSerially but that doesn't help. I also tried calling getDisplayHeight() as well and take the minimum of both values, but that doesn't work because if the width is returned as height then the status bar height is deducted and we end up with a display "width" value that is too small.

As a result, 1) my splash form (that has an image that is scaled to the display width) is first incorrectly shown - which is corrected while waiting for the next form to show, and 2) my GUI sometimes uses the wrong display width - so not the full width is used.

My question is how to make sure to get the correct (portrait) display width after a call to lockOrientation(true) when the device has to adjust from landscape to portrait.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are a lot of additional edge cases that reproduce this problem that you missed such as multi-tasking/side-by-side views etc. Display size can change even when locking orientation.

There are multiple things you can do such as override the components onLayout callback or listen to the forms size change event.

Comment: Yes I have to look at split screen too. Orientation locking does not work for split screen (on Android).